# Why has my wife stopped cooking food for me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My wife won't make me dinner.

Of course, everyone knows that it is poor form to hand or sell your lady's food back to her, but I haven't sold her food back to her

However, I have sold her food to a few merchants, and dropped some of her food in dungeons. Is it possible that this might be the reason she won't cook food anymore?

Is there any way I can fix this so she start cooking food again?

Comment: I've deleted comments from this question due to the comments in question being argumentative, degenerative, and accumulating flags.

Comment: Same happened to me after moving to solitud when I din't bought all furniture,after buying it all my spouse stopped cooking and this never fixed up,not evene returning at her house or the house we lived before.

Comment: You guys are no fun.

Comment: @GnomeSlice, we try to be fun, but our first responsibility is to the poor, tag-uninformed reader who might settle for [one daily virtual meal](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/41878/16) per day, or worse, forgo the [opportunity to become a werewolf](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42327/16) *in some other game* due to an ambiguous title... Once we ensure we're not undermining digital nutritional needs or lycanthropic opportunities, *then* we can embrace a little whimsy. :)

Comment: @Jaydles I think we agreed as a community [a while ago](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/821/question-with-vague-title) that these titles are generally OK.

Comment: ... otherwise you'd have to go around and worry about [random invasions of foreign countries](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118734/how-to-invade-a-independent-county) or ensuring that people out there aren't leaving their gear at 70% effectiveness due to not understanding what game has [optimal repair points](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115673/is-there-an-optimal-repair-point), both of which are probably far more common mechanics in games than wives cooking food for you

Comment: @spartacus, see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100/titles-should-be-stand-alone-summaries-of-questions-without-depending-on-tags).  Depending on tags to convey a title's meaning is becoming an impediment to new users getting a feel for a number of sites.  I'm not going around editing older ones - this one caught attention because the cute title was attracting comment noise that required mod attention.

Comment: [Better](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2521/3114) [get](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2190/3114) [editing](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2196/3114).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only receive one home-cooked meal per day.  Other than that, [this appears to be a bug experienced by other players](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Marriage#Homecooked_Meal_bug).  The exact trigger does not seem to be known yet.

Answer (score 3):

If you have sold the home cooked meal then your wife will stop cooking for you. I verified it in game and it does happen to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

On both my first and second run my wife stopped cooking for me after I became a werewolf. Even after I cured this character she never did start cooking for me again.

Answer (score -1):

This bug can activate when you use `addtofaction 19809 1` and `setrelationshiprank player 4`.

What you need to do is kill your wife, then resurrect after that and try to use these commands:

`addtofaction 19809 1`

`setrelationshiprank player (17)`

`setfamy 500`

`spouse homecookmeal set 50`

`spouse respect set 300`

`spouse half money set 500`

`spouse vampirism 1`

`spouse respect 300`

`spouse love 100`

After trying this code you will get a lover stone and a vampire wife and your wife can be a follower.

These commands will only work for the PC version.

Comment: Those commands do not work at all on the PC version.