# Is there an optimal repair point?

Tags: dead-island

In Dead Island, is there a cheaper time to repair a weapon, relative to its condition, or does each usage-by-hit cost the same to repair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's condition 70%, according to this: http://web.archive.org/web/20120603154301/http://www.dead-island.com/forums/dead-island-tips-tricks-guides/4266-optimal-repair-cost.html.

> - The repair cost does not increase by a static amount for every hit.
> - The repair cost seems to be about 3.6644 times the default value of
>     the weapon when durability is depleted.
> - The increase in repair cost
>     per hit follows an inverted parabolic curve.
> - The durability is, in
>     most cases, one less than the number of hits a weapon can inflict
>     before breaking.
> - There seems to be a base repair cost which is
>     about 33% of the value, thereby making the first hit always the most
>     expensive.
> - Summary: The optimal repair point is 70% durability. The
>     cost per hit is most expensive at 40% durability.